# How to paginate in Flask-SQLAlchemy for two same struct tables?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class (BASE, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = ''
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    advertiser_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))

class (BASE, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = ''
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    advertiser_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

Two tables have  same struct, how to query and paginate them with pageIndex and pageSize?

```
**one table**
.query.filter_by(advertiser_id=123).order_by(.id.desc()).paginate(pageIndex, pageSize, False).items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopes this helps

```
from functools import reduce

queries = [QL_ORDER_GROUP.query, QX_ORDER_GROUP.query]

query = reduce(lambda pre, next_: pre.union(next_), queries)

query.filter_by(advertiser_id=123).paginate(pageIndex, pageSize, False).items
```